# visited array used in array reduce function

Tags: reactjs

In the following code, I wish to declare an array called `visited` that can record the previously visited `{row.name}` in the loop delimited by ",", and display it in the second column. My question is how should I insert the code to populate the `visited` array?

```
<div className={styles.tbody}>
    {rows.map(row => {
        return (
            <div key={row._id} className={styles.tr}>

                <div key={`${row._id}.title`} className={styles.td}>
                    {row.name} <CompleteSVG/>
                </div>
                <div key={`${row._id}.status`} className={styles.td}>
                    {parent} {/* <-- display here */}
                </div>                                   
            </div>
        );
    })}
</div>
```

Comment: what event is visited

Answer (score 0):

You can use a state for this that will hold all of the previously "visited" and then you could display it whichever way you'd like.

**Example:**

```
const [visited, setVisited] = useState([]);

const onVisited = rowName => {
   setVisited(prev => ([
      // Spread previous value to avoid overwriting.
      ...prev,
      rowName,
   ]));
};

<div className={styles.tbody}>
    {rows.map(row => {
        return (
            <div key={row._id} className={styles.tr}>

                <div 
                    onClick={() => onVisited(row.name)}
                    key={`${row._id}.title`}
                    className={styles.td}
                >
                    {row.name} <CompleteSVG/>
                </div>
                <div key={`${row._id}.status`} className={styles.td}>
                    {parent} {visited.map(t => t)},
                </div>                                   
            </div>
        );
    })}
</div>
```

As for the comma separation, it can just be hardcoded as in the example.

Comment: Thanks, is it possible in reactjs to declare a variable outside rows.map rather than using state variable?

Comment: WDYM "outside rows.map"? If you are referring to using a simple variable ( `const` / `let` ) instead of state then not really. React is designed around producing renders upon changes in state (be it the component's state, or a state of any of the parent components).

Comment: In other words, if we want the UI to reflect changes in our data, we use state.